# How can I improve my cross-correlation methodology?

Tags: python, r, signal-processing

I will break my question appropriately to make it easier to explain. This is actually a short question but looks longer due to my plots so I apologize for that. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

#### Setup

I have a few locations that I am monitoring with sensors. The dataset that I have is a set of events that the sensors measured at different locations. The measurements themselves look like the following:

[image]

#### First take

I wanted to figure out if any of the events recorded by these sensors were correlated so I ended up computing the cross-correlation of these series (plotted below). The plot shows me that there seems to be some correlation between the sequences `V3` and `V10` but nothing to show a strong correlation. So I ended up revising my approach: I used a window to observe the events.

[image]

I took a time window of 40 seconds and plotted the time series again along with their cross-correlation with each other. This time, it gave me something encouraging. I can see a perfect correlation between 3 and 10 and 3 and 6.

[image]

and its corresponding cross-correlation plots.

[image]

#### Question

It looks like I should not be computing the cross-correlating the entire timeseries but rather only across a small window. This makes sense because I am not really looking to see if the entire time series is the same anyways. What I am really looking for is if there is a correlated event. If we assume that events beyond a certain time period need not necessarily be correlated then we can perhaps compute the cross-correlation for a sliding window that would be more accurate and notify only if it is greater than 0.8.

Well, at this point, I feel like I am reinventing the wheel and am hoping there are standard techniques to do this. Most of my data points would be zero with a sudden burst now and then. In that case, how can I make I conclusions (that there is indeed a correlation) stronger? I head about FFTs and DFTs. Would they be of any use here? Any comments?

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I thought this was more of a signal-processing related question and have definitely seen questions like this on SO before. Ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289415/what-is-a-good-r-value-when-comparing-2-signals-using-cross-correlation I did not come across many DSP people on Cross-Validated but I could be wrong.

Comment: maybe you should explain what you are trying to do in terms that are not technical.  do you expect to see the same event at different places at the same time, or the same pattern of events at different places at different times, or what?  it's not at all clear, because you are jumping into a (possibly incorrect solution) without explaining what on earth is actually important.

Comment: also ffts and dfts are just implementation details.  you really need to clarify what you *want* first.

Comment: @Legend : The question you link at is from before the crossvalidated-era... As the policy on SO got a whole lot stricter, I rather act before a bunch of others comes to downvote and close your question as off topic. It has happened before...

Comment: @andrew cooke: Sorry about that. I am expecting to see the same pattern of events at around the same time at different locations. If the number of events that were matched is higher, then it is better because it just gives me a higher confidence that the sensors it. Please let me know if I need to add more details.

Comment: @Joris Meys: Oh.. I didn't know about that. Thanks for the clarification. I don't think I have the permissions to move this though.

Comment: is the time difference the same for all events (eg because the clocks at different places have different offsets) or does it differ for each event (eg because the events are at different locations and have significant signal travel times)?

Comment: The time difference is the same for all events at the same location. Other than that, there could be a time offset between different locations. So for instance, if an event occurred at location 1 at t=200, then it might occur at say, t=205 at some other location. But I cannot say anything conclusive about event-pairs. For example: Event 1 and Event 2 @Location 1 at (200, 205) can occur at (205, 220) at Location 2. Their amplitudes are all I have in that case.

Comment: this doesn't sound like correlation, tbh - it sounds like some kind of cluster identification.

Comment: in seismology you have something similar.  an earthquake is detected at different times around the world, and the time differences depend on where it was.  so no two events have the same shift.  identifying which events belong together involves iterating with a model of where the earthquake occurred, and seeing what events fit.  do you have any physical "meaning" behind the delays in your case?

Comment: cross correlation will only help when all (or many) events have the same shift - when you want to ask "what shift aligns many events?".  if each event has a different shift then it is no help.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I will start off with a simpler question then (will also cross check my data if events have the same shift). If we assume that the events have the same shift but the locations could have different time offsets, would you have any suggestions? As for the physical interpretation, these sensors are monitoring some objects that are passing by and I am trying to see if two sensors are seeing the same pattern of objects (for instance, sensors at (X=10, and X=20) will observe the same pair of objects moving from X=0 to X=50 but at different times.

Comment: @andrew cooke: Just verified with a subset of events. It looks like events themselves have the same shift but could occur at different times at different locations.

Comment: ok, so that then the cross-correlation gives you the relative shift for each site.  you can use that to correct the times (so that the clocks all agree).  then you just look for events that occur at the same time at different sites.  make sense?

Comment: so you do cross-correlation once, on a large data set (eg perhaps once a day) between locations 1 and 2 and you find that the correlation has a peak at 10seconds.  so that means that the times at location 2 are 10 seconds after location 1.  so you take all the events at location 2 and subtract 10 seconds.  then the times at both sites agree.  so all then you don't need correlations any more - instead you just look for events at the same time.

Comment: Yeap. That explains it. Could you also comment on when I should use a window to compute the cross-correlation as opposed to computing it on an entire time series? I observed that in my dataset, using a window of about 40 (as noted in my question) gives me a better sense of correlated events. EDIT: Just reading your new comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, thanks for clarifying this in comments.  I'll try explain things more clearly here.

A cross correlation is really just a way of seeing what shift between two sets of data aligns best.  So if you have the same "pattern" at different sites, but the times are different because the clocks are badly adjusted (say), then a cross correlation will show a strong peak at the shift that corresponds to the time difference.

So you can use cross-correlation to find the time difference between two sites.  Once you have that, you can correct the times of the events at one site so that they agree with the other.  And then you can simply match up events by time.

Now, the next question is: over how long should you make the correlations?  In general, the longer the better, because you have more events and so will get a stronger signal.  But there is a trade-off, because you are assuming that the shift is constant over the length of the correlation, and if that is not true then you will get poor results.

To see that in more detail, lets assume that the time differences are due to clock errors, and that the clocks wander around slowly, so that over an hour they are pretty much constant (they don't agree, but they disagree by a fixed amount), but over a whole day they can have shifted backwards and forwards several times.  In that case, correlating over a day is too long - better to divide the data into hour-long chunks and cross-correlate each chunk separately.

Hope that makes sense!

PS I still don't know what you're detecting.  It's possible that you have something more complicated.  For example, events could come in "groups", where the time shift for events within a single group is the same, but different groups have different shifts.  In that case, what you need to do is identify the size (duration) of a group at one location and then use just the section of data that spans a single group, correlating it against other sites.